# Trying to remove an option from a multi select box - not working on ie

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove an option from a multi select box on click. Its working fine with Chrome and Firefox but not working with IE. I am adding some more options dynamically so I used delegate...

```
  $('#SelectedVacancyCategories').delegate('option', 'click', function (opt) {
            $('#SelectedVacancyCategories option[value="' + opt.target.value + '"]').remove();
            return false;
  });
```

The Developer Tools in IE doesn't thrown any error.

I tried using live and on but still the same problem. As I wrote it works with Chrome and Firefox and notwith IE.

Please comment if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of .live() try .on()....live() is depriciated...

Comment: boss i tried it but didn't work on IE..works on chrome and firefox though. @Exception

Comment: Can u please post some demo code on jsfiddle and share the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event on an option isn't supported by all browsers ([see here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html)). Why not just bind a change handler on the select, and remove the option selected?

```
$('#SelectedVacancyCategories').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option:selected').remove();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7C8fL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace with my function this code work ok

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#SelectedVacancyCategories').delegate('option', 'click', function (opt) {

            $(opt).remove();
            return false;
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select id="SelectedVacancyCategories" multiple>
<option value="123">
123
</option>
<option value="456">
456
</option>
</select>
</body>
```